# I('ve got it)/ (got it)/get it/understand it /understood it /'ve understood it

Tags: grammar

A teacher helped me with a question as in this conversation:

> Me: Could you please help me with this question?
>
> Teacher:Let me see. For this type of exercise, you should do like this,
> You should do that, this is correct, this is wrong.....
>
> Me: Thank you teacher, I__________it

I want to say that I understand the matter now:

(1) I 've got it.

(2) I got it.

(3) I get it.

(4) I understood.

(5) I 've understood.

(6) I understand.

Can I use any of them?
Is there any difference between them?

Comment: They all sound OK in this context, although "understand" might be more formal. They will not all work in every context: "I understood it yesterday" could mean you formerly understood but no longer understand it.

Comment: #2 is a "slangy" version of #1 (common in AAVE), #4 doesn't make sense, and #5 is "stilted" (and unlikely). Other than that, take your pick.

Comment: @StuartF, I can see that FumbleFingers doesn't agreed to use (4) and (5) for my context on my first post (asking a teacher). How about you? After reading your comment, I think that (4) and (5) can be used too.